# Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory does not work when exception is thrown from <p:ajax> inside <p:tree>

Tags: ajax, primefaces, exception, tree, omnifaces

I have the following code:

```
<p:tree value="#{blockTreeBean.tarifRoot}" var="node" dynamic="true"
            selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{blockTreeBean.selectedNode}">
   <p:ajax event="select" onstart="thePanel.openPanel();"
                update=":tarmedDetailViewer, @this"
                listener="#{blockTreeBean.onNodeSelect}"
                oncomplete="javascriptfunction()"/>
   ...
</p:tree>
```

When during the update of the tarmedDetailViewer a EL expression throws a NullPointerException I would expect to get a 500-error page. Instead I get the error logged and and the content with the exception will not be rendered. The Exception will is thrown in the xhtml on a event:

```
<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.initDto}"/>
```

The error page works if the NullPointer is thrown in a non-ajax request. It works if the onNodeSelect-method throws the NullPointerException directly. Also it works if the null pointer is thrown in the following context:

```
<p:commandButton value="hi!" id="ajaxbutton" icon="icon-arrow" ajax="true"
                                         action="#{bean.badmethod}"/>
```

My faces-config.xml contains:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

My web.xml contains:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error-500.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

Used version:

- Omnifaces: 1.5
- primefaces: 5.1
- Tomcat 8.0.15
- Upgraded to JSF Mojarra 2.2.10 (before JSF Mojarra 2.1.2)

**Update:** Any exception in the xhtml part will create this behavior, not just in the tag f:event.

Comment: This has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=116) before. It appeared to be Mojarra related as it works in MyFaces. Which JSF impl/version are you using? Perhaps I can take a look at it again.

Comment: @BalusC thanks! It looks pretty much like the problem reported in this ticket. And it's very likely a Mojarra  related issue. Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: When you said "JSF 2.1.2", do you mean "Mojarra 2.1.2"? That one is rather old. Have you tried the current 2.1.x (2.1.29) or even 2.2.x (2.2.10)?

Comment: @BalusC I tried now with both Mojarra 2.1.29 and 2.2.10 and have the same behavior.